# How to use search method for Lotus Notes document search

Tags: lotus-notes

My requirement is to collect the Lotus Notes documents which, for a given set of search terms, contain either:

- all of these terms,
- any of these terms
- or none of these terms.

I am using the `Database.FTsearch(...)` method by generating a query for the particular phrase and passing the query to that method. I found that there is another method: `Database.search(string arg1)`. How can I use that method for all the three of the conditions mentioned above?

Comment: if FTSearch is the faster solution, what made you ask about Search? Do you have problems with FTSearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NotesDatabase search method](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/14719175cd60410385256c54004ccbbc?OpenDocument) takes a formula string as its first parameter.  You can pass a formula such as:

```
@Contains(Body; "Word1") || @Contains(Body; "Word2") || @Contains(Body; "Word3")
```

Which would match the document if any of the three words were in the body.  To make it match on all words, just change the ORs (||) to ANDs (&&).

Note that this method searches through all documents without an index, and can be very slow if  there thousands of documents.  The [FTSearch method](http://blagoevgrad.court-bg.org/help/help85_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/59036b827c0025b18525748d00598adc?OpenDocument) is faster but requires you to turn full-text indexing on to work efficiently.

Comment: As my test, should it be @Contains(Body; "Word1") | @Contains(Body; "Word2") | @Contains(Body; "Word3").

Comment: @Matt Maybe it depends if we are talking about formulas in Java or formulas in LotusScript

Answer (score 0):

The Domino wiki has [an excellent discussion of when to use each search method and how to use them](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Searching_for_Documents).

Remember that the index for `FTSearch` is not updated instantly, even when the full-text index is set to update "Immediately". If you need up-to-the-moment results, you will either need to call `Database.updateFTIndex` first (which will impact performance) or use `Database.search`.

Also keep in mind that translating your FT queries may not be entirely straightforward. If you are building simple queries such as "Term1 OR Term2 OR Term3", this type of query searches every field in each document. That would take a fairly complex query to approximate in `Database.search` and it would probably perform poorly. If you are searching a specific field on the document for a value, it's more straightforward, as Ken describes in his reply. You will also need to use `@Abstract` if the field you are searching is rich text since `@Contains` only works with plain text.

Answer (score -1):

I found following links helpful

a) Search related wiki

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Searching_for_Documents

b) FTSearch Method details and example

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/c37507bc31ef178385256c54004db362?OpenDocument