# IBM Domino Java - optimize searching on $(Rooms) view for specific internet address

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm fairly new to IBM Domino. I have an XPages Java application that works as an extended API for the standard Rooms & Resoruce management database (allows me to manipulate appointments easily and offers more functionality than the standard API, such as modifying appointments of other people).

When I want to get a list of all appointments for a specific room, I pass the internet (mail) address of the room to my API, and in the Java app I iterate over the `$(Rooms)` view in `names.nsf` looking for documents until I find one with the `InternetAddress` item I'm looking for. I then get some other interesting information from the document such as the auto processing settings.

It works, but I'm pretty sure it's not efficient at all and I'm querying over 50 rooms, getting appointments for all of them takes about 18 seconds, and I'm not really satisfied with this result.
How could I optimize this? I'm pretty sure I can do some simple search on the view that will do everything under the hood in a more optimized way, but I haven't got enough experience to make it work.
My current code:

```java
        Session session = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Database names = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), "names.nsf");
        View vw = names.getView("($Rooms)");
        lotus.domino.ViewNavigator nav = vw.createViewNav();

        ViewEntry nextEntry = nav.getFirst();
        Document docRoom = null;
        while (nextEntry != null) {
            ViewEntry processEntry = nextEntry;
            nextEntry = nav.getNext();

            if (processEntry.isDocument() && processEntry.isValid()) {
                docRoom = processEntry.getDocument();
                // found
                if(docRoom.getItemValueString("InternetAddress").equals(mail)) {
                    processEntry.recycle();
                    break;
                } else { // not found
                    processEntry.recycle();
                    docRoom.recycle();
                    docRoom = null;
                }
            } else processEntry.recycle();
        }
        if(docRoom == null)
            return null;
        nav.recycle();

        String fileName = docRoom.getItemValueString("MailFile");
        String fileServer = docRoom.getItemValueString("MailServer");
        String fullName = docRoom.getItemValueString("FullName");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're running 50 times over all available view entries. Because of that it takes too much time. Time complexity of your approach is `O(N*M)`.

There's more efficient way to get a document from view by key.

```
Document doc = view.getDocumentByKey(yourKeyValue);
```

It runs way more faster (`O(LogN)` time complexity), but it requires that the view should contain the first sorted column with the `yourKeyValue` values. In our case, we should have a view that has `InternetAddress` as the first sorted column.

Unfortunately `($Rooms)` view does not apply to this rule. The first column of this view contains different data, than we need.

I would create a new view in the `names.nsf` for the task.

Let's name it `(RoomsByInternetAddress)` and put the following formula as selection formula for the created view:

```
SELECT ((Type = "Database") &(ResourceFlag="1") & (ResourceType="1") & (AutoProcessType != "D")) & (Form="Resource":"Database") & @IsUnavailable($Conflict)
```

It is the actual formula for `($Rooms)` view.

Make the first column of the view sorted and set the first column value to the `InternetAddress` field.

Then save it and close it. As it is closed, in the view properties (in the designer view list), enable "Prohibit design refresh or modify". It will protect the new created view from removing upon refreshing from the original server `names.nsf` template.

[image: view properties setting]

After that in your code you do not need to walk over all entries.

```
View vw = names.getView("(RoomsByInternetAddress)");

String InternetAddressIWantToFind = "someroom@company.com";
Document foundDoc = vw.getDocumentByKey(InternetAddressIWantToFind, true);
if (foundDoc != null) {
   // you've found the document by InternetAddress
}
```

---

**Update**

For cases when you are not authorized to change server's `names.nsf` there is another option.

IBM Domino Java API `Database` class [supports search() method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_SEARCH_METHOD_JAVA.html).

Here's info about search formula syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770367/12576990

Comment: I think I unfortunately cannot create a new view in the database,  it could work on my own server but if I wanted to deploy it to some client then I would need to have permissions to create a new view in the server's directory database. Is there any other way? For example issuing the selection formula programatically?

Comment: If the database is signed by the server id, as it is custom in many deployments, your code can run with server permission and you can create that view. But more interesting: Starting with R10 you have DQL query language that is super fast